# If this is consider a proper React form component how would you get data back?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to put into practice what I've learned and created one form that I can use across an app.

How would I get data back from the form, I understand I can pass some functions, but is it possible to pass a function as props that need arguments? I have also posted a link to a code sandbox with the component.

[Form Component](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-rain-2x5kg?file=/src/page/DisplayForm.js)

Comment: You can pass functions that need arguments like any other prop.

Comment: It's very common to pass callback functions to your child components as props. See the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) for examples.